# _getch returns smiley faces

Tags: c++, getch

I'm trying the function below to get a filename while allowing for 'ESC' press to go back

but for some reason **_getch() always returns [1 '\x1']** and what is being printed is a **smiley face**, even for BackSpace (which is nice and all, but absolutely not what I want to happen).

- What's going on here?

Other insights on how to improve the code are more than welcome! (I've recently finished my first year in college so I'm still pretty new to programming)

```
string& Get_Filename()
{
    char ch;
    string name;

    while (ch = _getch() != 'CR')
    {
        if (ch == 'ESC')
            throw RESTART;
        if (ch == 'BS')
        {
            name.pop_back();
            cout << 'BS';   // Also, will this correctly delete or will I need to
        }                   // << '\b' << ' ' << '\b'?
        else
        {
            name += ch;
            cout << ch;
        }
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: [Look at all the help the compiler can give you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e044ea885e4fc358) Please please please turn on and/or up the warning level.

Comment: Returning reference of local variable! It should print unhappy faces not smiley ones!

Comment: You need to use `"` for strings, not `'`. Don't use getch. Use `string input; cin >> input; if (input == "CR")`

Comment: Actually, in the context of my program it works just fine since I copy it but thanks, I forgot a lot of things...

Comment: No it's not fine. It works by accident and can blow up on another compiler.

Comment: 'CR', as far as ASCIItable.com goes, is the character for Carriage Return (One of the two things the 'Enter' key sends) and not a string I'm looking for...

Comment: @user2962533, `'CR'` in C++ has nothing to do with a carriage return. As the compiler warns you. You're looking for `'\n'`, which would be a CRLF for you.

Comment: @Neil Kirk Of course I'll fix it and never do it again. I just mentioned that it works in the context of my program...

Comment: @user2962533, It works in the context of the compiler, the compiler version, the OS, the OS version, the machine, and the moon phase.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "context of my program". Despite the fact that you may copy the returned reference in another variable, it's still dangerous. But I'm happy if you won't do it again :)

Comment: @chris I have 0 warnings on VS2013, how do I turn it up?

Comment: @user2962533, http://i.imgur.com/p1idViG.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about operator precedence here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

One of the problems is in the line

```
while (ch = _getch() != 'CR')
```

since `!=` has a higher precedence than the assignment operator

what you're actually asking is:

```
while( ch = (_getch() != 'CR') )
```

and thus getting the result of the expression instead of the character you wanted (which is the *integral conversion* bool->char defined in the standard §4.7/4 as 0 or 1)

Furthermore: you're returning a reference to a local variable. Make sure to return a by-value copy or something which doesn't fall out-of-scope.

Finally: `_getch()` returns the character read from the console, you can't "intercept" special key chords (e.g. Ctrl-D or Esc). Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/078sfkak.aspx

Comment: Also care with the reference to the local variable!

Comment: Is there any way that'll allow me to intercept 'ESC' and the like, then?

Comment: `while ( (ch = _getch()) != 0x1B )`, notice the parenthesis